C++ : MultiThreading : Parallelism is taking more time than Sequential
I am using threading in c++, on MAC for the first time.
Below is my code. (Motivation behind my code)
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

using namespace chrono;

const long long maxLimit = 2e9;

void getEvenSum(long long &sum) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= maxLimit ; i+=2) {
        sum += i;
    }
}

void getOddSum(long long &sum) {
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= maxLimit ; i+=2) {
        sum += i;
    }
}

int main() {
    
    auto startTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    long long evenSum = 0 , oddSum = 0;
    thread evenSumThread(getEvenSum, ref(evenSum));
    thread oddSumThread(getOddSum, ref(oddSum));

    evenSumThread.join();
    oddSumThread.join();

    auto endTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(endTime - startTime);

    cout << " final sum is " << evenSum << " " << oddSum << endl;

    cout << " time taken with thread :" << duration.count() / (long double)1e6 << endl;

    

    startTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    evenSum = 0 , oddSum = 0;
    getEvenSum(evenSum);
    getOddSum(oddSum);

    endTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(endTime - startTime);

    cout << " final sum is " << evenSum << " " << oddSum << endl;

    cout << " time taken without thread " << duration.count() / (long double)1e6 << endl;

    return 0;

}

OUTPUT :
 final sum is 1000000001000000000 1000000000000000000
 time taken with thread :5.01665
 final sum is 1000000001000000000 1000000000000000000
 time taken without thread 2.83442

The output is quite unexpected. Threading takes 5 seconds and non-threading takes 2.8 seconds. HOW !!!
Solutions I have tried and failed,

g++ --std=c++11 file.cpp
g++ --std=c++11 -O3 -s -DNDEBUG file.cpp ( time changed frantically, but still threading takes more time )
g++ --std=c++17 file.cpp
g++ clang++ -std=c++11 file.cpp ( Got error, that "CLANG" not present )
Tried changing XCode->Product->Scheme->Change Scheme ( Doesn't open any menu for changing scheme, Dead end )
Above commands I have tried in VS code, as well as MAC terminal (iterm). I tried changing VS code build from "DEBUG" to "RELEASE", that also doesn't help.

PS : The same code used to work when I had practiced last time in the Linux (2 years back)

You are right @AhmedAEK , and what you got, is expected. I just want to know, what is it in the MAC compiler configuration that I need to change, such that I get same behaviour as Windows and Linux. ( I have done on linux same program, it works as expected.

can you only put the timing result of 2, the one with -O3 , also try -O2 and add those timings to the question, the other configurations are irrelevant.

under high optimization both recent gcc and clang optimize all the code away and just return the result instead of performing any calculations. godbolt link , you can force them to emit the code ewith volatile

I checked the godBolt link you have shared. I got your point of view. Assembly language instructions, I am not much interested in. If there is some command which can enforce the second thread to spawn on another core ?
I tried giving flag -volatile to g++ command, it doesn't work.

The code I have written, works perfectly fine on WINDOWS and LINUX, its just the MAC which has restrictions.

@NeerPatel have you tried profiling simple thread creation on Mac?  Sometimes thread creation can take a while.

@RichmarIII . I have tried multiple times. Also monitored Activity monitor. What my understanding is,,, MAC is allowing only one CORE to the g++ compiler. So, when one thread is doing computational work, another thread can't proceed.
Now, instead of writing the for loop in the evenSum() and oddSum() functions, If i simply write this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(2)) then threading is faster than sequential. ( don't forget to include  and using namespace chrono ).
Its just MAC putting boundaries on g++ causing these errors.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

When I compile your code (with -O3 under linux gcc 8.3.1), getEvenSum and getOddSum return fixed constants (e.g.) getEvenSum is just: getEvenSum(long long&): movabsq $1000000001000000000, %rax addq %rax, (%rdi) ret So, maybe macos takes longer to start/stop threads. You might be able to test this by changing the thread functions into no-ops. Or, have each thread function do its own pair of high_resolution_clock::now calls. Also, disassemble the code on both linux and macos to ensure macos code is the same. What CPUs? (e.g. x86_64, arm, etc.) What Mac system (e.g. M1, M2, ...)?

MAC Intel 7, Intel UHD 630 graphics.

You should enable optimizations like -O3. on most recent gcc and clang with -O3 both functions are completely optimized away, you can prevent that optimization by declaring its argument as volatile.
void getEvenSum(volatile unsigned long long& sum) {
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i <= maxLimit; i += 2) {
        sum += i;
    }
}

this also convert the variables to unsigned long long to avoid signed overflow which is undefined behavior.
The second problem is now false sharing, one way around it is to pad both variables away from each other, or align those variables to cache line boundaries (hint: use std::hardware_destructive_interference_size, since C++17)
    alignas(64) unsigned long long evenSum = 0;
    alignas(64) unsigned long long oddSum = 0;

with that the multithreaded version is now faster than the single-threaded version. online godbolt result
By disabling those optimizations We went from the function taking 0 time to some time ... so did we really make the code faster ?!

Wish, things were simple like in windows and Linux . Mac has its own way of forcefully optimising things. if you ever find something simple to use, with command on g++, please do share. I can't write above code in interviews. Otherwise, interviewer keep digging, why you have used the volatile and alignas() . I want some smooth/simpler way with commands.

@NeerPatel you can manually add padding by putting both variables in a struct with a char[64] between them ... but the proper way is to use alignas , the struct trick won't pass a code review. you only need volatile when compiling with optimizations, without -O3 you don't need volatile, but you still need the padding, even more because without optimizations the computer loads each variable from the RAM twice each iteration, same as when using volatile

It is even worse @OP doesn't synchronize with the results (e.g. didn't use std::future/std::async). So the results are not to be trusted anyway

@PepijnKramer thread.join is a synchronization point The completion of the thread identified by *this synchronizes with the corresponding successful return from join(). , reading the result before it is a race, reading the result after it is 100% valid code

@AhmedAEK I feel so stupid... I just didn't see the joins somehow :/

The OP could also have their functions return the value instead of take a reference into another thread.  Writing to non-local memory in a thread is code smell.

I completely agree with @Ahmed AEK's answer. Additionally, as I presume you might have provided a simplified sample of your scenario, I would like to propose another possible solution for such cases using OpenMP. This might help you speed up the loop unrolling parts of your code, which could be faster in scenarios involving more complex and heavy computation in loops.:
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

const long long maxLimit = 2e9;

void getEvenSum(long long &sum) {
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxLimit; i += 2) {
        sum += i;
    }
}

void getOddSum(long long &sum) {
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxLimit; i += 2) {
        sum += i;
    }
}

int main() {
    auto startTime = high_resolution_clock::now();

    long long evenSum = 0, oddSum = 0;
    
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            getEvenSum(evenSum);
        }
        #pragma omp section
        {
            getOddSum(oddSum);
        }
    }

    auto endTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(endTime - startTime);

    cout << "Final sum is " << evenSum << " " << oddSum << endl;
    cout << "Time taken with OpenMP: " << duration.count() / (long double)1e6 << endl;

    startTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    evenSum = 0, oddSum = 0;
    getEvenSum(evenSum);
    getOddSum(oddSum);

    endTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(endTime - startTime);

    cout << "Final sum is " << evenSum << " " << oddSum << endl;
    cout << "Time taken without OpenMP: " << duration.count() / (long double)1e6 << endl;

    return 0;
}


Thank you. if you ever find simple command with g++ , please let me know.
I can't write this much code during 45 minutes interview. I need something simple.
